# Unable to write on firestore emulator

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-tools

I was able to read data from the firestore emulator but cannot add any data to it throught the client which is an android app.

This is the error:

```
W/Firestore: (24.0.0) [Firestore]: Write failed at Users/vBLloPGsMJrXGDZdZcVO: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
```

My firestore.rules file in local environment

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
    allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code used to write to firestore

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users")
            .document(userId)
            .set(newUser)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){

                Log.d(TAG, "new user has been added");
               

            }else {

                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to add new user"+Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getMessage());


            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: It looks like your code doesn't have enough permission to write to the database according to its [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

Comment: i have shown my firestore.rules file

Comment: please add to the question the code you are using to write to firestore

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're trying to update a document (different from writing one). Try to add "update" in your firestore security rules like so:

```
allow read, get, update: if true;
```

Comment: `write` = `create` + `update` + `delete`, so updates are covered in OPs rules. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations